# whats the point of a constraint class in symfony 2?

Tags: symfony

Working with validators I saw that I had to create a constraint class where I just set an error message, that make me think that there is something weird... what's the point of a contraint class?, just add an error message?, I'm comming from zend, new in symfony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, it's just [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). In this case, the constraint class is only [responsible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) for encapsulating configuration for validation (e.g., error message).

Comment: so validator is just for validation, and constraint for error message

Comment: Yes, but not limited to error messages. For example, the Image constraint defines validation options like min/max height/width.